# Organize different layers of repeating texture

Tags: textures, blender, uv-mapping

I'm using Blender for creating assets for a 3D video game (FPS). Particularly i have to create a long wooden fence and i'd like to use one 700*700 texture for the entire fence so different part of fence would just have different UV coordinates. This scenario looks ok to me so far.

Meanwhile i'd like to bake Ambient Occlusion, and different panels must have different AO, so i need another UV Map here.

I don't know much about influence of multiple UV maps on performance (if there's such influence at all or that's very engine dependant). Could you please advice me what option to choose (or at least any pros and cons):

1. Use two different UV maps: one for colour/spec/normal and one for AO (and maybe shadows). I heard this approach is bad because different UV layers slow down pipeline.
2. Bake colour/spec/normal on the same UV map that AO uses. This way leads to a great redundancy, but i will have one UV map.

Comment: It's common enough for engines to have tiling textures for color/normal/spec and a separate, fully-unwrapped UV set for baked lightmaps, so that every surface can have unique lighting.  But if you're making art for a specific engine, you'll need to determine what that engine supports and go from there.